# Add Remove cordova plugin not reflecting in iOS - Mutliple Targets

Tags: ios, cordova, plugman

We have an Ionic Project and iOS as platform. Based on our needs, we keep adding and removing plugins from the cordova project. Currently we have 2 targets in our iOS XCode Project(One original target and another a duplicate). Adding plugin using Cordova/Plugman is not reflecting files correctly in the 2nd target. No source/header/resource file mentioned in “plugin.xml” is getting added to 2nd target. What’s the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to write hooks if you are using the same the cordova plugin.